# firewalld vs CSF on a Centos 7 VPS

Tags: linux, centos, security, firewalld

I just got a new GoDaddy dedicated VPS and I am trying to secure it.  Its Centos 7.7 and the WHM does not come with any installed FW that I can tell.  On an older VPS `configServ security and firewall` was pre-installed (but not active) on Centos 6.8 WHM.  I tried getting it running once, ran into trouble and backed out never to touch it again.

But now I need to get a FW operational.  Are both firewalld and csf just front ends to using iptables?  Or are they completely different?  Which is easier to use, which has a better gui interface?....is the protection the same?  Is there even a gui for firewalld - if so, how do I access it because I can't seem to find anything?  It appears I have both firewalld and iptables installed (are iptables always installed?):

```
~]$ systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

For iptables I get this:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner GID match mailman
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner GID match mail
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             localhost            multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner UID match cpanel
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner UID match root

# systemctl status iptables
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

So...is iptables actually running...or not?  Please help me make sense of all this.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalld and iptables are two different things, both can let you reach the same target, as they both basically do the same thing: checking which packet can pass and which has to be blocked.

To simplifly the concepts, you can consider firewalld as a mountain dam and iptables as a downstream barrier.
Firewalld works as a service, so when it's running you should see this:

```bsh
# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor p>
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-05-07 00:41:29 CEST; 1 day 17h ago
```

accordingly to your output, your firewalld process is not active and probably your provider disabled it as it wants you configure it by yourself. Be careful when you try to activate it! I don't know what kind of setup your GoDaddy VPS has, but just as example, if you connect with SSH and the port 22 is locked, you lock yourself out and you will not able to do anything anymore!

On the other side, your iptables looks already configured and active. iptables works in a different way, so don't waste your time to lookf for an iptables process, as it isn-t!

iptables works as a kernel modules and the kernel manage directly the sent and received packets; accordingly to your output the filtering is already active and your firewall is up.
If it wasn't you would have seen such an output:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

It seems your VPS has a cPanel, so for sure you can find a module that let you configure your firewall(s) easily.
Unfortunately I cannot give any advice about csf as I never used it, anyway for sure is a valid product (and a good firewalld alternative) as it has its own big followers.